# Does Mojo use jslint nomen flag backwards?

Tags: maven, jslint, mojo

In my pom.xml file which I use for my project I've set the following up for jsLint:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jslint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <executions>
            <execution>
                    <goals>
                            <goal>jslint</goal>
                            <goal>test-jslint</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>

            <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/vendor/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And at the top of my js-file I have the following:

```
/*jslint nomen: true, browser: true, devel: true*/
```

And within the file I have a method called:

```
Api.prototype._call = function (query) {...};
```

Which I call like this:

```
Api.prototype.product = function (options) {
            ...
            return this._call(query);
        };
```

**And now for the strange things...**

If I compile this with `mvn clean install` I get the following error message:

```
api.js:45:29:Unexpected dangling '_' in '_call'.
```

But if I revert the flag for nomen to say `nomen: false` mvn does not complain!

This on the other hand leads to that IntelliJ marks the `_call` part of the code with a red marker since it is beaking jsLint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly looks like a bug in the "jslint-maven-plugin" plugin.

The [official JSLint docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) say nomen is "`true` if names should not be checked for initial or trailing underbars." You can also verify that with the [options checkboxes on jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/#JSLINT_OPTIONS).

The "jslint-maven-plugin" source code appears to have it backwards: if you search for "nomen" in [the source code](http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/jslint-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/jslint/AbstractJSLintMojo.java), you'll see they have it mapped to something called `disallowDanglingUnderbarInIdentifiers` -- the *inverse* of what `nomen` means.  (I'm not entirely sure how that translates into overriding the config settings *in* the JS file, but it certainly seems suspicious).

It looks like you can [file a bug here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJSLINT) on the plugin, if that's any consolation.